# How do you invoke a function in a module which is in a package?

Tags: python

I have a project structure of:

```
root_dir/
└── app/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── mymodule.py
```

inside of mymodule.py I have the following function:

```
def hello():
    print('hello world')
```

If i call python from inside the root directory I'd like to do the following:

```
>>> import app
>>> app.mymodule.hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'mymodule'
```

Is there anyway to invoke the hello function?

Comment: Add `import mymodule` to `app/__init__.py`? Otherwise you have to `from app.mymodule import hello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jonrsharpe comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353968/how-do-you-invoke-a-function-in-a-module-which-is-in-a-package#comment75709853_44353968) is right. When you reference a package you are referring to the `__init__.py` module and this module doesn't contain any reference to `mymodule`. That's why you cannot do `app.mymodule` in the first place.